# Sonar - can't handle C# attributes?

Tags: attributes, sonarqube

got this error, Sonar isn't familiar with attributes in c#?

```
06:35:14.881 ERROR - Parse error at line 13 column 21:

    8: 
    9: using xxx;
   10: 
   11: namespace wwww
   12: {
  -->      [ServiceContract]   
   14:     public interface  IContactsChartService
   15:     {
   16: 
   17: 
   18: 
   19: 
   20: 
   21:
```

Answer (score 0):

An upgrade to the C# plugin version 4.0 (which is based on Roslyn) should fix this issue.